# How do I detect digit separated by space using regular expressions in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract 10 or 13 digit numbers from a text. The formats of the number are like this: 2442141411 or 2 442141411 or 24 42141411  or 2 44214141 1. The can be present or not. I wrote following regex:

```
reg = r"\d{10}|\d{13}"
```

But it fails for `2 6 9 32 2 3 8 376 67` or `2 6 9 32 2 3 87 77 67` or `2 6 9 32 2 3 8 37667` or .....  these types of input.

the output should be `2693223837667` for the first one, for the second on `2693223877767` and for the 3rd one `2693223837667`.

Comment: `But it fails for...` Can you show us _all_ the expected types of matches here?

Comment: does your text file contain `or` as a separator ?

Comment: You missed something important in "_The can be present or not._"

Comment: There is no `or` separator in the text.

Comment: To clarify, you want to extract strings that contain 10 or 13 digits and then remove the spaces?

Answer (score 1):

This would match a sequence of 10 or 13 digits, with white space present:

```
(?:\d\s*){10}(?:(?:\d\s*){3})?
```

However, if you only want to allow a single space between digits:

```
(?:\d\s?){10}(?:(?:\d\s?){3})?
```

Note that this may still not be what you need, if your text can also contain strings of (for example) 12 numbers and you don't want to match the first 10. For example, when matching this:

```
My phone numbers are 0123 456 789 and 00 98 456 123 789 and my credit card 1234 5678 9012 3456
```

You may only want to match `0123 456 789` and `00 98 456 123 789` but not `1234 5678 9012 3`. So, you may want:

```
(?<!\d)(?:\d\s*){10}(?:(?:\d\s*){3})?(?!\s*\d)
```

For the given example, it will match only `0123 456 789` and `00 98 456 123 789`.

Perhaps a bit of an explanation: `(?<!\d)` is a lookbehind and checks that there's no number immediately before the match. `(?:\d\s*){10}` matches ten digits with any number of spaces between them, you can swap `\s*` for `\s?` to only match a single space. As indicated in comments, `\s` matches any whitespace, including newline, you can also just replace it with a space, if that's not needed. The `?:` at the start avoiding matching the group specifically, I assume you're only interested in the whole match. `(?:(?:\d\s*){3})?` matches another three numbers just like the first 10, but the `?` at the end makes this optional, i.e. 10 or 13 numbers. And finally, `(?!\s*\d)` is a lookahead, making sure the number isn't followed by another number, possibly preceded by more spaces.

In Python:

```
import re

text = """My phone numbers are 0123 456 789 and 00 98 456 123 789
and my credit card 1234 5678 9012 3456"""

print(re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?:\d\s*){10}(?:(?:\d\s*){3})?(?!\s*\d)', text))
print(re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?:\d ?){10}(?:(?:\d ?){3})?(?! ?\d)', text))
```

Result:

```
['0123 456 789 ', '00 98 456 123 789\n']
['0123 456 789 ', '00 98 456 123 789']
```

Note how the first example includes the newline in the result.

Comment: The first regex has a few problems, one being that it spans line breaks. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/b1UNXH/5/)

Comment: @CarySwoveland if you want to avoid linebreak matching you can replace `\s` by `[ ]` and it will only match space

Comment: That fixes one problem but your regex matches `"1234567890123"` in the string `"1234567890123456789"`. Requiring the string to be exactly 10 or 13 characters in length is central to the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland read to the end, that's what the final example solves. I.e. 'my regex' doesn't match that, only the first example does because it's trying to show how to solve the basic problem of matching that number of digits.

Comment: I don't follow. The second regex doesn't match, for example, `"2 6 9 32 2 3 8 376 67"`, one of the 13 digit examples given in the question. Shouldn't it? [ref](https://regex101.com/r/b1UNXH/6/).

Answer (score 1):

You can match string of interest with the following regular expression, after which spaces would be removed.

```
r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d )(?:(?:\d *){13}|(?:\d *){10})(?<! )(?! ?\d)'
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/b1UNXH/4/) <sub><sup><</sup>¯\*(ツ)*/¯<sup>></sup></sub> [Python code](http://tpcg.io/Ie5M1Ihe)

To confirm the number of digits is 10 or 13 it is necessary to require that the string not be preceded by a digit or a digit followed by a space and not be followed by a digit or a space followed by a digit.

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<!\d)        : assert match is not preceded by a digit
(?<!\d )       : assert match is not preceded by a digit followed
                 by a space
(?:            : begin a non-capture group
  (?:\d *)     : match a digit followed by 0+ spaces
  {13}         : execute non-capture group 13 times
  |            : or
  (?:\d *)     : match a digit followed by 0+ spaces
  {10}         : execute non-capture group 10 times
)              : end non-capture group
(?<! )         : assert preceding character is not a space
(?! ?\d)       : assert following character is not digit
               : optionally preceded by a space
```

Comment: Was going to fix this on mine (got called away) but I see you've covered it anyway.